# Configure proxy for Chrome on xubuntu for school

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy

I need to configure a proxy for google chrome, because we use this for school. The proxy looks something like this: `http://pol*************.edu.au/b***.p**`
It is easy in firefox, I just set it to automatically detect proxies.
Although I have searched in the forums, I have not found an answer easy enough for me to understand.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a proxy autoconfiguration (PAC) file to test this with, but I think the following commands should work:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url 'http://pol*************.edu.au/b***.p**'
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode auto
```

The descriptions for these fields:

`org.gnome.system.proxy mode`:

```
Select the proxy configuration mode. Supported values are "none", 
    "manual", "auto".

    If this is "none", then proxies are not used.

    If it is "auto", the autoconfiguration URL described by the
    "autoconfig-url" key is used.

    If it is "manual", then the proxies described by
    "/system/proxy/http", "/system/proxy/https",
    "/system/proxy/ftp" and "/system/proxy/socks" will be used.
    Each of the 4 proxy types is enabled if its "host" key is
    non-empty and its "port" key is non-0.

    If an http proxy is configured, but an https proxy is not,
    then the http proxy is also used for https.

    If a SOCKS proxy is configured, it is used for all protocols,
    except that the http, https, and ftp proxy settings override
    it for those protocols only.
```

`org.gnome.system.proxy autoconfig-url`:

```
URL that provides proxy configuration values. When mode is
    "auto", this URL is used to look up proxy information for all
    protocols.
```

Comment: Ok, I have entered the commands. Ill see if it works tomorow at school.

Comment: Hey Muru, it looks like it will work at school, but at home, these settings create an error message on chrome: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED. Is there a way to switch between the two modes? (auto proxy and none)

Comment: Ok I got it: to switch between them I type: gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy auto and gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy none, and reboot. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Barnabas looks like I made a mistake, the command is supposed to be: `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode auto` (and conversely `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode none`) - with **`mode`**. You shouldn't have to restart.

Comment: ok. cool, I will use these instead... :)

Comment: Hey muru, the proxy ultimatly did not work at school. When I opened google chrome, the page loaded for hours and did not end up loading at all. With firefox it worked. Another thing I would like to mention is that whereas firefox asked for my school username and password to access the internet, chrome did not. I would really like to use chrome at school, because all my important settings and bookmarks and webapps are there. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: @Barnabas hmm. Well, the last option I can think of is to use a command line flag. Close all Chrome windows (and background processes), then run `google-chrome-stable --proxy-pac-url="http://pol*************.edu.au/b***.p**"`. Also try `google-chrome-stable --proxy-auto-detect`.

Comment: thankyou. I will try it tomorow. If this dosn't work, ill just use mozilla...

Comment: Ok. It does not work. I will just use Mozilla from now on. Thanks for all your efforts, however. :)